# rewrite php/sql code to make it more streamlined

Tags: php, mysqli

I really don't like looking at this code, it's dirty to me and needs to be condensed into tighter code. I feel like it could be done in a single query and making the query inside the while loop instead of before...

However, every time i try to put the SELECT inside the while it fails out. how should i condense this? Here is the datalist for an input form:

```
<datalist id="keys">
<?php
  $tile1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM YearMakeModel GROUP BY Make1, Model1");
  while($storeModel=mysqli_fetch_object($tile1))
    { echo '<option value="'.$storeModel->Model1.'">'; }
  $tile2=$db->query("SELECT * FROM YearMakeModel GROUP BY Make1");
  while($storeMake=mysqli_fetch_object($tile2))
    { echo '<option value="'.$storeMake->Make1.'">'; } 
  $tile3=$db->query("SELECT * FROM YearMakeModel GROUP BY Make1, Model1");
  while($storeMakeModel=mysqli_fetch_object($tile3))
    { echo '<option value="'.$storeMakeModel->Make1.' '.$storeMakeModel->Model1.'">'; }
?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I would start with outputting html code with echo. This way you have only one block of PHP code...

Comment: The MySQL grouping operator is not there to help with the presentation of the data. Just select all rows and sort them in the order you want before populating the options.

Comment: @apokryfos not sure I understand... I think I'm doing that already with the Group By in each select. Can you give example?

Comment: @JRsz good suggestion! that does look better, but i still think i could do this with just 1 query instead of 3. but i just cant make it work.

Answer (score 0):

All your results can be obtained by doing the following:

1. Get all data
2. Group them up in the distinct fields
3. Write them in the output

This can be done as follows:

```
$everything=$db->query("SELECT * FROM YearMakeModel");   


$formattedResults = [ "models" => [], "makes" => "makesAndModels" => [] ];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($everything)) {
      $formattedResults["makes"][$row->Make1] = "Make label here?";       
      $formattedResults["models"][$row->Model1] = "Model label here?"; 
      $formattedResults["makesAndModels"][$row->Make1.' '.$row->Model1] = "Combined label here?"; 
}

<datalist id="keys"> 
    <?php 
    foreach ($formattedResults as $array) {
          foreach ($array as $value => $label) {
                 echo "<option value='$value'>";
          }
    } ?>          
</datalist>
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.